# Saving mutiple integer in mysql database laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, integer

when I try to save my data into the database, for some reason I can only save 1 integer and not multiple integer inside. Can anyone tell me why? I was thinking it might be because I am using FamilyAge as an integer in the database instead of a string.

Here is the screenshot of the data in my database, sorry for the weird data I put, I just type some random words for testing.
As you can see in my screenshot, last row, I am suppose to save 3 datas but for the family age part only 1 data is saved.
[image]

family_info controller(this is how I saved it)

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{

  $personal_info = Session::get('data');

  $data7 = array();
  $data7['NameOfFamily'] = implode(' , ', $request->NameOfFamily);
  $data7['Relationship'] = implode(' , ', $request->Relationship);
  $data7['FamilyAge'] = implode(' , ', $request->FamilyAge);
  $family_info = new family_info;
  $family_info = family_info::create($data7);
  $family_info->personal_infos()->associate($personal_info);
  $family_info->save();

}
```

familyInfos table:

```
Schema::create('family_infos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';  
    $table->string('NameOfFamily');
    $table->string('Relationship'); 
    $table->integer('FamilyAge');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Your data type should be varchar to store strings. As you are adding comma separated age.

Comment: @Suraj thanks for replying, what do you mean by my data type must be varchar? How do I do that? I only know in the database I can set it as varchar but how do I do it in code. Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your schema you are using an integer type for FamilyAge `$table->integer('FamilyAge');` which should be a string to store comma separated values `$table->string('FamilyAge');`

I suppose you are trying to save the family age like this `22, 45, 56`

```
Schema::create('family_infos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';  
    $table->string('NameOfFamily');
    $table->string('Relationship'); 
    $table->string('FamilyAge');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

> I recommend you to read this
>   https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#columns which explains how to
>   create the Laravel migration